# What is the correct way to convert SVN remote branches and tags into local Git branches/tags during SVN to Git migration

Tags: git, git-svn

What is the correct way to make the remote branches/tags that exist after a git-svn init/git-svn fetch into local Git branches/tags before pushing to my remote Git repo and abandoning SVN altogether.

I have:

- Run `git svn init`
- Updated the `svn-remote "svn"` section of my .git/config file to the following:

  ```
  url = file:///Users/Developers/git_transition/svn_repo
  fetch = cascade/trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
  branches = cascade/branches/{5.0GA_CLEANUP,drag-n-drop-def-builder,help-text,hib-annotations,hibernate-annotations,image-editor,ldapconfig,liquibase,move-rename-prototype,progress-bar,progress-bar2,quartz-upgrade,recyclebin,rendering_metrics,shuttle_upgrade,spring3,web-services-no-nuller}:refs/remotes/svn/*
  branches = cascade/branches/{6.x,5.x,4.x,3.x,archive}/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
  tags = cascade/tags/{3.7.x,4.x,5.x,6.x,old-releases}/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
  ```
- Run `git svn fetch`

Does `git-svn clone` do something beyond init/fetch that turns these branches/tags into local ones?

I tried the [advice on Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch8-1.html) but there was nothing in the .git/refs/remotes/svn/ directory except the empty 6.x, 5.x, 4.x, 3.x, tags, and archive directories. I did verify that the remote branches are there with `git branch -r`.

Someone suggested that I needed to systematically checkout all of the remote branches as local ones: `git checkout -b <local_branch_name> <svn_remote_branch_name>` but I haven't gotten a definitive answer anywhere.

I **have** been able to conver the tags by using this script:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/svn/tags/6.x |
grep -v @ | while read tag; do GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1
--pretty=format:"%ad" "$tag")" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(git log -1
--pretty=format:"%ce" "$tag")" GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$(git log -1
--pretty=format:"%cn" "$tag")" git tag -m "$(git log -1
--pretty=format:"%s%n%b" "$tag")" ${tag#refs/remotes/svn/tags/6.x/}
"$tag"; done
```

for each of the tags folders.

Answer (score 3):

For a one-shot operation like this, before leaving behind a SVN repo, I like to clone it using the ruby script **[svn2git](http://github.com/iteman/svn2git)**

> === Examples
>
> Say I have this code in svn:

```
  trunk
    ...
  branches
    1.x
    2.x
  tags
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

> **`git-svn`** will go through the commit history to build a new git repo.
>   **It will import all branches and tags as remote svn branches, whereas what you really want is git-native local branches and git tag objects.**
>   So after importing this project I'll get:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
  $ git branch -a
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
    tags/1.0.0
    tags/1.0.1
    tags/1.0.2
    tags/1.1.0
    tags/2.0.0
    trunk
  $ git tag -l
  [ empty ]
```

> After `svn2git` is done with your project, you'll get this instead:

```
  $ git branch
  * master
    1.x
    2.x
  $ git tag -l
    1.0.0
    1.0.1
    1.0.2
    1.1.0
    2.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at svn2git but didn't see an easy way to configure it to look for branches/tags in all the places that I mentioned in my config. What underlying commands does svn2git use to turn remote branches into local ones?

Comment: @Bradley: any remote svn branch will be created as a local Git branch after that script is run. The idea is not using a 'git-svn' clone, but making a *new* Git repo cloning the svn repo through the script. Leave your current Git repo (from the git-svn clone) aside.

Comment: Am I able to specify the varied branch/tag locations in the SVN repo that I mentioned in my .git/config file when running the script.

Answer (score 3):

According to an answer on Git mailing list, I don't need to convert these branches into local ones before pushing them to my remote repo. I just need to do:

```
git push <remote_git_repo_name> svn/<branch-name>:refs/heads/<branch-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

To do exactly that you want just use [SubGit](http://subgit.com) project. You can install it into your SVN repository. So that a linked Git repository is created (with SVN tags translated to Git tags, svn:ignores to .gitignore and so on). That Git repository is kept in sync with the SVN repository: when you push to a Git repository, this changes is translated to the SVN repository, and vice versa.

If you need client-only solution, I would recommend you to use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It also preserves SVN concepts in Git repository.

And what I wouldn't recommend you to use it git-svn.

Comment: SubGit is non-free and you didn't mention it.

Comment: @Onlyjob SubGit is free for one-shot conversion which is the case for this question, as far as I understand. One has to pay for SubGit only if one uses git-svn mirror mode, when both SVN and Git access is enabled. So I think Dmitry's answer is fine in this regard.

Comment: I meant license, see [The Free Software Definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy/straightforward way to convert SVN tag-branches to native git tags after `git svn` conversion. There are number of scripts out there to convert SVN tags but most of them merely tag-&-remove corresponding branches outside of "master" branch so new tags won't show up in commits history even if "master" have commits identical to the tagged ones.

In order to solve this problem I ended up writing my own utility "[git-svn-convert-tags](https://gitlab.com/onlyjob/git-svn-convert-tags)" which finds and tags commits identical to SVN "tags" within "master" branch. The logic is simple: utility compares all commits in current branch (e.g. "master") to tag-branches' HEADs. When binary-identical commit is found new tag is assigned and SVN tag-branch is deleted. Using this approach I've managed to successfully convert tags in many *git-svn* imported repositories to perfect git tag layout.

Comment: Actually you can use svn2git --rebase to actively mirror an SVN repository to a GIT repository with equivalent branches/tags. I've been using the script that way with good results.

Comment: You have to ensure that the --prefix option  you used for git svn init/clone is "svn/" because that's what the svn2git script itself uses. If you cloned without a prefix, the default prefix used will be "origin/" which requires a one-time conversion. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pcbeard/c4669960a2d3dfee601dd8f930079c60) for a script that makes this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example on how to convert one of these branch references to a tag:

```
# rename the branch reference
git branch -t rel_20101019 remotes/svn/tags/rel_20101019

# checkout the branch
git checkout rel_20101019

# create the tag for it
git tag rel_20101019

# go back to master
git checkout master

# delete the branch
git branch rel_20101019 –d

# now you can push your branch and tag changes to your origin
git push origin –all
git push origin –tags
```