# Git: Converting tag to branch in remote repo

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I have a tag called **latest** and I want that to be a branch instead. Opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357403/converting-git-branch-to-git-tag). I need to remove it from the remote repo as well.

Background: This is currently a problem for many **golang** packages, where **goinstall** looks for a **release** tag or branch, which corresponds with the latest official release of the language. Many people mistakenly used git *tags*, by analogy with other VCSes, when they should have used git *branches*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git checkout latest
git tag -d latest  # delete tag locally
git push origin :refs/tags/latest  # delete tag in repo
git checkout -b latest
git push origin latest
```

The danger of removing a tag is [described here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging), but that is why a branch should have been used in the first place.

Comment: I don't believe a delete followed by a create is the same things as a converting an existing tag into a branch. Was it the case (is it still the case?) that one cannot convert a tag into a branch? That question does not appear to be answered.

Comment: A "branch" (really a "head") is nothing but a file like `.git/refs/heads/mybranch`, containing just a SHA1. A "lightweight tag" is also just a file containing a SHA1, like `.git/refs/tags/mytag`. So you *could* simply `mv` that file. But an "annotated tag" is a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the tag use a branch of a different name. Use different naming conventions for your branches and your tags. This will better allow you to fullfil the spirit of

- Branches are for changes, tags are for releases
- Don't delete tags

Comment: Ideally, yes. The problem is that lots of people have created tags they should not have. In other VCSes, tags can be moved, so they apply the same model to git. I'll change the word *release* to *latest* to make it more clear.