# Is there a simple command to convert a branch to a tag?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I am about to complete a tedious process of converting "dumb snapshots" to git. This process has been going very well (thanks to [this rename process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628539/how-to-tell-git-that-its-the-same-directory-just-a-different-name/6629505#6629505)), but now I realized that some of the branches that I created, do not merit a `branch` but rather a `tag`.

Since everything is still local (never pushed to a repository), I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357403/converting-git-branch-to-git-tag) (and associated answer) somewhat more cumbersome than I prefer, so I was wondering whether I can take a shortcut via some simple "convert-from-branch-to-tag" command?

Is there such a simple command to convert a branch to a tag?

(I know I can just leave it as is, but I really like the way `gitk` highlights tags, helping me easily identify them).

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Andy's answer below, I managed to come up with a shell script that does it all conveniently and painlessly. I am sharing this script for the benefit of all and as special thanks to this great community who made moving from CVS to git possible for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCHNAME=$1
TAGNAME=$2

echo "Request to convert the branch ${BRANCHNAME} to a tag with the same name accepted."
echo "Processing..."
echo " "

git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/heads/${BRANCHNAME}
# $? == 0 means local branch with <branch-name> exists. 

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   git checkout ${BRANCHNAME}
   git tag ${BRANCHNAME}
   git checkout master
   git branch ${BRANCHNAME} -d
   echo " "
   echo "Updated list branches, sorted chronologically: "
   echo "---------------------------------------------- "
   git log --no-walk --date-order --oneline --decorate $(git rev-list --branches --no-walk) | cut -d "(" -f 2 | cut -d ")" -f 1
else
   echo "Sorry. The branch ${BRANCHNAME} does NOT seem to exist. Exiting."
fi
```

Comment: [Here I described an effective method to convert SVN tag-branches to git tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20807602/815781)

Comment: *"Is there a simple command..."* - nearly nothing in Git is simple or matches basic workflows, so that one is liikely easy to answer: NO. What ever follows *simple* does not matter :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Was there separate development on these branches? (the post you linked to, doesn't appear to have development on those branches)
If there was no development, you could:

1. Checkout the branch `git checkout branchName`.
2. Tag it with `git tag tagName`.
3. Switch back to master `git checkout master`.
4. Finally, delete original branch with `git branch branchName -d`.

This can also be done if there was development on the branch, but you will need to use `-D` instead of `-d`.  I'm not a git pro though, so not sure if that is an *"acceptable"* way to leave a branch.

Comment: Thank you. No, there was no development on those branches whatsoever. The `git checkout <branchName>` and the `-d` at the last step are what scared me, but I now understand that there is no other way. So I will have to experiment with this on a safe copy of the entire git (local) repository.

Comment: If there was no development on that branch a tag is every bit as good as a branch (in the end they are both just pointing to a commit).  Using the _little_ d will ensure that you can safely delete the branch and not lose work.

Comment: I just finished verifying that your 4-steps process works for me. See the shell script I wrote that reflects that. Thanks again and answer accepted now.

Comment: Isn't it better to use annotated tags? git tag -a tagName

Comment: @Quantum7 I don't think one is better than the other.  They each have their own purpose.

Comment: don't forget to `git push --tags`

Comment: It's unnecessary to checkout the branch first (as can be seen by the other answers).

Answer (score 47):

The answers given are basically correct.

As tags and branches are just names for objects, there is a simpler way without touching current work area:

```
git tag <name_for_tag> refs/heads/<branch_name> # or just git tag <name_for_tag> <branch_name>
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

Or even do it to remote server without touching local repository at all:

```
git push origin origin/<branch_name>:refs/tags/<tag_name>
git push origin :refs/heads/<branch_name>
```

Comment: Oh man. it is simple. I guess I over-engineered in my answer a bit :)

Comment: Wow... i never thought this can be so easy! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Per Andy's answer, I've made an alias that can also be used for the same thing:

```
[alias]
branch2tag = "!sh -c 'set -e;git tag $1 refs/heads/$1;git branch -D $1' -"
```

**Usage**

If you want to convert branch bug-2483 to a tag (while your main branch is master) write:

```
git branch2tag bug-2483 master
```

**UPDATE 1**

Changed to reflect the solution proposed by kauppi.